# Name for a problem where the unknown is a vector of integers and the data points are proportional to it?

Tags: estimation

I've got an unknown vector of integers I, an unknown constant c, and my data are cI + noise. The noise has mean 0. The problem is to estimate I.

I know that it's possible, because if you had an infinite number of data and made a histogram it would have peaks that would be c apart. From that you could infer c, and then estimate I by dividing your data by c.

But I wish I could look up standard solutions to the problem. My problem, basically, is that I don't know what this situation is called or where to read about it.

There are other details to my problem--for example, a specific kind of heteroskedasticity to the noise that I explained in the comments. However, it would help me find any sources on any problem where cI+noise is estimated, even if it doesn't reproduce all the details of my problem.

Comment: What do you know, or assume, about the noise? About $c$? Are the $I$ considered fixed constants each of which you need to infer or from some random process (e.g. counts in a Poisson process) whose characteristics you want to make inferences about? (i.e. What problem are you solving?)

Comment: Do you have an a priori idea of how many different integers? If fairly small, and you also are willing to assume a parametric family like a normal, this seems to have a lot in common with "mixture distributions", for which there is some literature.

Comment: @Glen_b: the noise has mean 0. I tend to assume it's normal. Also, I_i represents a number iid random variables that get summed together before recording the observation--each with its own noise--so the variance of the noise is proportional to I_i. Regarding I, these are what I really want to know. The problem is to infer the vector I. So, I tend to think of them as fixed constants, but that's the kind of modeling choice I would really like to have some guidance from the stats literature on, and I really don't know where to look in this case.

Comment: @Russ: It actually is fairly small (usually 0-6, with occasional jumps up to the 10-50 range). I'll look into that.

Comment: Your intuition may be faulty here.  If the variance of the noise is approximately $c^2$ or greater, the peaks you envision will merge and the histogram could even reduce to just a single peak (depending on the values of $\mathbf{I}$). Deconvolving this into its components may be impossible unless you know precisely the dimension of $\mathbf{I}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that these models are called "quantal models". There's [a good review by Çankaya and Fieller](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/02664760802466195).